# How to find a simple function with those very specific properties?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question

I'm looking for a function `F : N -> N`, for `N < 10`, such that:

```
F(1) == F(4)
F(2) == F(5)
F(3) == F(7)
F(0) != F(1) != F(2) != F(3) != F(6) != F(8) != F(9)
F(N) < 8
```

So, for example, `F(N) = Nth element of [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6]` would satisfy.

That function is allowed to use simple algebra (`mul`, `add`, `mod`, `sub`, `div`, `exp`), but not `if` nor "faking ifs" with multiplications - i.e., I don't want to be obvious what the function is doing. The simplest the formula, the better. I tried looking for all the functions of a linear congruential generator with `M, C < 50`:

```
F(n) = (n * M + C) `mod` 7
```

But none of those had the desired properties. Is there any clever way to find such a function?

Comment: What does the the "chain" of "not equal" statements mean? are all the function values different, or just the adjacent pairs in the chain?

Comment: All are different, @Joffan.

Comment: Your list example doesn't work/make sense what is the 0th element and f (1 doesn't see to equal f (5)

Comment: In my opinion "no faking IF with mult" is too restrictive.  There's nothing wrong if a seven degree polynomial.

Comment: @fleablood I'm sorry, the original question was wrong. It is fixed now, triple checked it. As long as the formula is simple and looks obfuscated, not making the special cases obvious (i.e., `F(n) = if n<4 then n, else if n == 4 then 1...`) it is ok...

Comment: I found a nice answer though: `F(N) = P(N) mod 7; P(0) = 69; P(N) = (P(N-1)*3+1) mod 59`! :D

Comment: So basically 0,6,8,9 must be different from all others.

Comment: @fleablood Yes! That was fun to solve to me, but I of course took a computer scientist approach. Feel free to try it too!